# What does "Copy" means in a job description?

Tags: job-search, job-description

When looking for new opportunities, I noticed "Copy" accompanying job description, e.g. "Creative Director (Copy)", "Associate Art Director, Copy", etc.

I assume it's some kind of description of the position seniority, but cannot find any explanation anywhere.

Answer (score 14):

If these job opportunities are in advertising, this is likely for [copywriting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copywriting).

> Copywriting is the act of writing text for the purpose of advertising or other forms of marketing.

Comment: Note that not all copywriting jobs are in advertising.  These positions can also be for internal communications in large corporate environments for example.

Comment: its for a creative director, not a writer.

Comment: I like @RichardU 's answer better than mine.

Answer (score 8):

Copy refers to text, the "copy" that will be worked on.  This is specifically text to be published and not graphics or other artwork.

In the case of a [Copy Editor](https://www.sfep.org.uk/about/faqs/what-is-copy-editing/) it is someone editing the "Copy" to make it suitable for publishing.

So, in the case of this position, you would be dealing with a creative director who would be dealing with text only.  He would have nothing to do with any sort of artwork, graphics, film, et cet.

Now, the text could be anything from adverts, scripts, novels, even the words published in a comic book.

More detail in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_(written))

Comment: @marcheenek No, copy stands for text, which I clearly stated

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the company advertising this job uses an [ATS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applicant_tracking_system), which is software for automating large parts of the hiring process. They might have copied this vacancy from a previous, existing vacancy, and their system might be configured in such a way that it adds this `(Copy)` text to copied vacancies. If that's the case, the recruiter who set up the vacancy has simply forgotten to delete that.

It's a bit strange though to see that in several places.

Source: I work for a company that makes such a product.